# How do I annotate a List of Lists of Strings using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb, marshalling

Say I have the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo1")
public class Foo1
{
    @XmlElementWrapper( name="answerList" )
    @XmlElement( name="answer" )
    private List<String> answerList;
}
```

If Foo1 instance is marshalled, it would look like this

```
<foo1>
    <answerList>
        <answer>myAnswer1</answer>
        <answer>myAnswer2</answer>
    </answerList>
</foo1>
```

Now, if I have the following property:

```
private List<List<String>> answerListsList;
```

**How do I annotate the property above so I would have the following XML (of course, without creating a new class to hold a list of Strings)?**

```
<foo1>
    <answerLists>
        <answerList>
            <answer>row1 myAnswer1</answer>
            <answer>row1 myAnswer2</answer>
        </answerList>
        <answerList>
            <answer>row2 myAnswerA</answer>
            <answer>row2 myAnswerB</answer>
        </answerList>
    <anserLists>
</foo1>
```

EDIT:

The reason for not wanting to create a new class is I'm trying to avoid creating too many classes. Creating a new class for every List of Lists of Strings that you might have, which happen to use different element names, is not a good design in my opinion.

I can consider creating a new class as an answer as long as that class can be marshalled into different element names and element wrappers as per need. For instance, that class should be able to represent the following XML:

```
<answerLists>
    <answerList>
        <answer>row1 myAnswer1</answer>
        <answer>row1 myAnswer2</answer>
    </answerList>
    <answerList>
        <answer>row2 myAnswerA</answer>
        <answer>row2 myAnswerB</answer>
    </answerList>
<anserLists>
```

or

```
<myLists>
    <myList>
        <item>row1 d1</item>
        <item>row1 d2</item>
    </myList>
    <myList>
        <item>row2 dA</item>
        <item>row2 dB</item>
    </myList>
</myLists>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the XML that you want, without creating a new class!

I wrote this class:

```
@XmlRootElement( name="foo1" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo1<T>
{
    @XmlElementWrapper( name="answerList" )
    @XmlElement( name="answer" )
    List<T> answerList = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Usage for List in List is this:

```
Foo1<Foo1<String>> ff = new Foo1<Foo1<String>>();
```

But the output XML isn't how you want it, because the XML you want to get, can't be produced without creating a new class!

Comment: I'm not sure if that cannot be done without creating a class. Maybe if you could cite me a credible source that says so, I would accept your answer. But then again, the reason ask for a solution that doesn't require a new class is because I already know a solution that requires one. The problem with creating a new class is you would have an explosion of classes. There would be a new class for every List of Lists of Strings you may have that use different element names.

Comment: @supertonsky if you don't like the you can't you simply might want to add "as aar as Ilya nows ... and this is a valid workaround ..." and upvote the answer since it at least offers the only solution so far.